# How to convert body back to xml or json string in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, node.js

In my nodejs I have this:

```
var xmlparser = require("express-xml-bodyparser");
// var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(xmlparser());
// app.use(bodyParser.json());

//....
```

And debugging:

```
 > req.body
    { key1: { key2: [ [Object] ], key3: [ [Object] ] } }

 > typeof req.body
    'object'
```

I do need to have access to the body of a request as a dictionary, however, I also want to be able to store 
body as an xml or json string in a database. How can I convert "req.body" back to xml string or json string?

Comment: you could add your own middleware that runs before the xml parser and stores the xmlBody on the request in it's original form. converting an object back to xml is unlikely to get you the original xml document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make as below:

```
var example = 
{ key1: { key2: [ [Object] ], key3: [ [Object] ] } };

// Convert to String
var result = JSON.stringify(example);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() converts json to string. JSON.parse() converts json string back to object